# check for a string in Map.Entry in for loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing Firebase push notification. I'm getting push notification using `remoteMessage.getData()`. I'm using Map.Entry in for loop to get data. As shown I'm getting the key and value pair as:
key: body, value: {JSON Object} ; key:title, value: Placebid.
What I want is to get the key with string "title" and check if its "Placebid" and if yes then get the value of the key "body" which has the JSON. How to do this inside for loop? I tried but not getting the value of JSON.

```
//onMessageReceived
if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            try {
                System.out.println("sammy_getData "+remoteMessage.getData());
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()) {
                    String key = entry.getKey();
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    Log.d("sammy_ ", "key: " + key + "\n value: " + value);
                    System.out.println("sammy_key: "+key+"\n value: "+value);
                    if(key.contains("title") && value.contains("Placebid")){
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(value);
                        String jobid = obj.getString("job_id");
                        String username = obj.getString("username");
                        String msg = "bided on your job.";
                        String msgbody = username + " " + msg;
                        sendnotificationbid(jobid,msgbody);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

```html
//Push notification format

{
  body={
    "image": "<Image link>",
    "job_id": "1349",
    "id": 121,
    "message": "New Message Received",
    "type": "Placebid",
    "username": "User1234"
  },
  title=Placebid
}
```

Comment: `if(...value.contains("Placebid")) { JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(value);}` it doesn't make sens ... because value = Placebid

Comment: Why do you need a for loop If you know your key is "title"? Directly get the value using the key from map and check if it is equal to "Placebid".

Comment: Can you show me how to a small example for this? @AkshayBhat

Answer (score 0):

Since your `title=Placebid` in notification format is outside the **body** tag, when you call `remoteMessage.getData()`, it returns a map of data which is only inside **body** tag.
If your notification format is changed like below (moving title=placebid inside body), it will work.

```
//Push notification format
{
  data:{
    "image": "<Image link>",
    "job_id": "1349",
    "id": 121,
    "message": "New Message Received",
    "type": "Placebid",
    "username": "User1234"
    "title":"Placebid"
  }
}
```

And no need of for loop when you know the key you are looking for is "title". Directly get the value using the key from map and check if it is equal to "Placebid".

**Edit:**
The notification data json should be like example json below and the key is not **body**, it is **data**.

```
{
"to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
"data" : {
  "image": "<Image link>",
    "job_id": "1349",
    "id": 121,
    "message": "New Message Received",
    "type": "Placebid",
    "username": "User1234"
    "title":"Placebid"
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. The format is now exactly as you have said. Now how to parse it? @Akshay

Comment: in `onMessageRecieved(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method, call `remoteMessage.getData()` which will return Map. then check if `map.containsKey("title")`.